# if line starts with “|” merge with the line above it

Tags: regex

I have data that looks like this:

```
123456789
|123|123|123|123|123
123456789
|123|123|123|123|123
123456789
|123|123|123|123|123
```

Is there a possibility to merge any line that starts with `|` with the one above it?
for final result

```
123456789|123|123|123|123|123
123456789|123|123|123|123|123
123456789|123|123|123|123|123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    ^(.*)\R\|(.*)$
Replace: $1$2
```

### Demo

Make sure that dot all mode is *disabled* here (the replace dialog should have an option for making dot match newlines; this option should be disabled).

Comment: not exactly the required output. dropping the line's leading `|` on merging lines

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the simplest way:

https://regex101.com/r/xTRM6T/1

Find: `\n\|`

Replace: `|`

Comment: not exactly the required output. dropping the line's leading `|` on merging lines

Answer (score 1):

```
Find:    [\r\n]+\|
Replace: |
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4U7zTM/1)

Comment: other answer did throw away the line's leading `|`, but the question required simply merging without loosing this character